# How to use codenameone cloud features?

Tags: codenameone

I have been using parse for backend for my codenameone project. I will like to use the codenmaeone cloud services instead. IS there any documentation and examples of how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page 111 in the developer guide: http://www.codenameone.com/developer-guide.html

There is also JavaDoc: https://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CodenameOne/javadoc/com/codename1/cloud/package-summary.html

And some additional info in the blog regarding new tools: http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2013/04/cloud-object-viewer.html

There is always the discussion forum where you can search and ask questions: http://www.codenameone.com/discussion-forum.html